Correlate Twilio Function logs with the Twilio Studio Flow execution that triggered them
I’m working with Twilio Services (not classic functions) and Twilio Studio, and I’ve run into a challenge. I have multiple Studio flows, several triggering a Twilio Function. However, I’m having trouble correlating the logs from the function execution to the specific Studio Flow execution that initiated it.
I’ve considered adding custom parameters to the flow or using specific logging strategies, but I’m curious how others have solved this problem.
Have you faced a similar issue? How do you ensure you can trace logs from a function back to the triggering Studio Flow? Any best practices, tools, or tips would be greatly appreciated!
